# Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignContext' in your configuration

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-feign

I am trying to run the application but this error keeps prompting.

**Description**:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.clientui.clientui.controller.ClientController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignContext' that could not be found.

**Action**:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignContext' in your configuration.

Here is the code:

**Main**

```
    package com.clientui.clientui;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients("com.clientui")

public class ClientuiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClientuiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
package com.clientui.clientui.controller;

import com.clientui.clientui.beans.ProductBean;
import com.clientui.clientui.proxies.MicroserviceProduitsProxy;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class ClientController {

    private final MicroserviceProduitsProxy produitsProxy;

    public ClientController(MicroserviceProduitsProxy produitsProxy){
        this.produitsProxy = produitsProxy;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String accueil(Model model){
        List<ProductBean> produits =  produitsProxy.listeDesProduits();
        model.addAttribute("produits", produits);
        return "Accueil";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 34):

I had the same problem when updating the spring-boot version to 3.0.0, I think it's some compatibility bug with spring cloud and spring boot's autoconfigure.
I solved it by adding the annotation `@ImportAutoConfiguration({FeignAutoConfiguration.class})` in the application, in your case:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients("com.clientui")
@ImportAutoConfiguration({FeignAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ClientuiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClientuiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked in my case!

Comment: Seemly need more action: Adding dependency `spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer` .

Answer (score 5):

I use Spring Boot 3.0.0 and faced the same issue and resolved it by using ***2022.0.0-RC2*** version of **spring-cloud-dependencies**. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/2022.0.0-RC2/reference/html/). It should work with Spring Boot 3.0.0.

If you are using Maven add this to your `dependencyManagement` section in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
  <version>2022.0.0-RC2</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note: For the time I am writing this answer ***2022.0.0-RC2*** version is not available in central repository but you can find it in Spring Lib M repository so you should also add it to your `repositories` section in pom.xml:

```
<repository>
  <id>lib-m</id>
  <name>Spring Lib M</name>
  <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/</url>
</repository>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignAutoConfiguration;

@ImportAutoConfiguration({FeignAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Adding these line on main app fixes the issue.

Comment: @ImportAutoConfiguration(FeignAutoConfiguration::class)

for Kotlin

Answer (score 3):

I was getting same error while updating springboot 3.
I resolved this issue by adding bellow in my main application

```
@ImportAutoConfiguration({FeignAutoConfiguration.class, HttpClientConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: How is this answer different from the Fozix one?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring 3.0.0 the "spring.factories" has been removed. The automatic import of autoconfigurations is broken if your dependency uses this.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#auto-configuration-files

The one way to fix this on your side without modifying the dependecy itself is using @ImportAutoConfiguration({ list of autoconfiguration classes }) explicitly. You can also use new functionality "imports file" provided by Spring. The right way is to migrate "spring.factories" to "imports file" on the dependency side.

Answer (score 0):

For my side, needed to add both this configuration classes :

```
@ImportAutoConfiguration({FeignAutoConfiguration.class, HttpClientConfiguration.class})
```